# Mirroring perforce with SVK?

Tags: svn, perforce, svk

Anyone know of a way to use SVK with perforce?  The docs [seem to imply](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/MirrorVCP) it used to be possible, but some [mailing list messages](http://lists.bestpractical.com/pipermail/svk-devel/2007-February/000604.html) claim that is no longer the case?

Comment: You might get better answers if you state more clearly what you want to acheive by using SVK or some other tool...

Comment: Am I the only one weirdly redirected here by GitHub Copilot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a private repository, you should try [P5](http://www.releng.com/p5layer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why use SVK to mirror Perforce? Surely using a [Perforce Proxy](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4p.html) is the best way to make your repository distributed?

Comment: Perforce proxy isn't quite what I'm looking for - I want to maintain a private repository for intermediate checkins.  I guess ideally we should be using branches here, but that's not really an option.